# Read content of manifest in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a project using angular. I am trying to use the angular progressive web app features.The app running perfectly. Now I want to come a situation where i need the read the value from manifest file, but i dont know how can i achieve this.

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "short_name": "xxxxxx",
  "theme_color": "xxx",
  "background_color": "xxx",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./index.htm",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xxxx.png",
      "sizes": "76x76",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xxxx.png",
      "sizes": "120x120",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xxx.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xx.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xxx.png",
      "sizes": "168x168",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xxxx.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/xx.png",
      "sizes": "640x640",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your (app) component:

```
  constructor(
      private readonly httpClient : HttpClient
    ) {
      this.httpClient
        .get<any>('manifest.webmanifest')
        .subscribe( o => {
             console.info(o);
         });
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe:  https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f